# MYSQL appear error #1292 when delete record with in 7 day at 2021 first week

Tags: mysql, date-arithmetic

i got a problem for MySQL , last week , i get the error when run this MySQL script

```
delete from calendar.schedule 
WHERE startdate >= DATE(NOW()) - 7 and status = 'ready'
```

it will display

> #1292 - Incorrect datetime value: '20210100' for column 'startdate' at row 1" error .

my testing date is 2021/1/7 , if i change the Mysql script to

```
delete from calendar.schedule 
WHERE startdate >= DATE(NOW()) - 6 and status = 'ready'
```

it will work normally. now, this code has no issues. but it will have bugs in the first week of the next year. anyone can help with this? Many Thanks!

Wilson

Answer (score 2):

Your issue is with this expression:

```
DATE(NOW()) - 7
```

When you try to subtract `7` from a date, MySQL converts the date to its integer representation (in this case I presume it was `20210107`) and then subtract 7 from it, giving `20210100`. It then tries to compare this to a datetime column and fails, since `20210100` is not a valid date. The code works when you use `6` because you end up with `20210101`, which is valid. What you should be doing instead is subtracting an interval (see the [manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/expressions.html#temporal-intervals)) so that you use date arithmetic, not integer arithmetic:

```
CURDATE() - INTERVAL 7 DAY
```

Note that `CURDATE()` is equivalent to `DATE(NOW())`

Answer (score 1):

If you do date arithmetic with integers as you are doing, the date is converted to an integer in the format YYYYMMDD, and then the value is subtracted.

The problem is this can produce a result integer that is not a valid date.

For example if NOW() is '2021-01-10' as it is right now when I run that expression, then `DATE('2021-01-10) - 10` evaluates as `20210110 - 10` which is `20210100`.

But there is no date with `00` as the day. The subtraction should be `2020-12-31`, right? But when doing integer subtraction, that's not what you get.

Solution: Use date arithmetic, not integer arithmetic. You can write date arithmetic in either of the following ways:

```
DATE('2021-01-10') - INTERVAL 10 DAY

DATE_SUB('2021-01-10', INTERVAL 10 DAY)
```